# File not uploaded in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to upload my file using php. But, dont know why it is not working. please help.

**My code:**

```
<?php
  error_reporting(0)
  $name = $_FILES["file"]["name"]; 
  $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
  if(isset($name))
  {
    if(!empty($name))
    {
        echo "OK <br>";

        $location = "uploads/";
        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location))
        {
            echo "uploaded";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "file not uploaded";
        }

    }
    else
    {
        echo "Please select a file";
    }
  }


?>
```

**HTML code:**

```
<form action="<?php $PHP_SELF ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT!">
</form>
```

Comment: surely you can provide better troubleshooting information than `it's not working`

Comment: what is the output your getting? 
try to check upload_max_filesize in the php.ini

Comment: Are you sure you have write permissions in the directory for the user running the server?

Comment: I am getting "file not uploaded", i.e. it is going in my else loop.  File is not uploading. YES, i have write permission.

Comment: I guess you didn't close the first `if`s braces. In the end, can you put `}` and try again?

Comment: No..still not working.

Comment: turn error reporting on and show us your error messages

Comment: start with removing error_reporting(0)or even replace with error_reporting(E_ALL);  and paste error message.

Comment: instead of `$location = "uploads/";` use Absolute path ex - `$location = "/var/www/projname/uploads/";` `echo dirname(__FILE__);` will also give you the absolute path to the current directory where you php file is in.

Comment: one more thing - you must append the file name to location your final code should be

`$location = "/var/www/projname/uploads/".$name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the full path for `move_uploaded_file()`. Also, `is_uploaded_file()` will suffice for your first two `if()` statements.

Update your code as follows:

```
$file = $_FILES['file'];

if( is_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name']) )
{
    $destination = 'uploads/'.$file['name'];
    echo (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $destination)) ? 'uploaded'
                                                               : 'file not uploaded';
}
else
{
    echo 'Please select a valid file.';
}
```

Please make sure that the relevant permissions are set on your `uploads/` directory.

Comment: This update not working..

Comment: Which `echo` statement do you get? What are the permissions on `uploads/`?

Answer (score 0):

you must set destination file name

```
                $name = $_FILES["file"]["name"]; 
                $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
                if(isset($name))
                {
                    if(!empty($name))
                    {
                    echo "OK <br>";

                    $location = "uploads/".$name;
                    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location))
                    {
                        echo "uploaded";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    echo "file not uploaded";
                    }

                }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "Please select a file";
                    }
                }


?>
```

Comment: this code works for me.

Comment: Do you have uploads/ directory side of your script ?